# sorting names and scores

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Ok so, i have two arrays. one with the names of the players and other with their scores. like this:

Array 1 : [0] - John | [1] - Mary | [2] - Nicholas | [3] - Thomas

Array 2 : [0] - 20 | [1] - 5 | [2] - 29 | [3] - 26

what i'm trying to do is to sort both these arrays using the quicksort method and the code below.

```
void quick_sort(int arr[4],char arr2[4][20],int low,int high)
{
 int pivot,j,temp,i;
 char *temp2;
 if(low<high)
 {
  pivot = low;
  i = low;
  j = high;

  while(i<j)
  {
   while((arr[i]<=arr[pivot])&&(i<high))
   {
    i++;
   }

   while(arr[j]>arr[pivot])
   {
    j--;
   }

   if(i<j)
   {
    temp=arr[i];
    temp2=arr2[i];
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    strcpy(arr2[i], arr2[j]);
    arr[j]=temp;
    strcpy(arr2[i], temp2);
   }
  }

  temp=arr[pivot];
  temp2=arr2[pivot];
  arr[pivot]=arr[j];
  strcpy(arr2[pivot], arr2[j]);
  arr[j]=temp;
  strcpy(arr2[j], temp2);
  quick_sort(arr,arr2,low,j-1);
  quick_sort(arr,arr2,j+1,high);
 }
}
```

After this, when i printf the arrays instead of giving me this (what i wanted):

1. Mary - 5 points
2. John - 20 points
3. Thomas - 26 points
4. Nicholas - 29 points

it outputs me this:

1. John - 5 points
2. John - 20 points
3. Nicholas - 26 points
4. Nicholas - 29 points

i've been looking at the code and i cant find the problem. do any of you guys have any suggestion? i need to deliver this by midnight

EDIT: i was given by my teacher the code to sort the scores in an array, but also gave us another array with the names of the players, it was already sorting the scores and she told us to make it work for the names aswell, thats what i cant get to work

Comment: Shouldn't have waited so long to ask questions. You aren't explaining this very well. You gave us your given output but never said what you're actually doing with the code. Do you have to do it like an idiot would and use two arrays or can you use objects like you should? Is this a final problem for a class, if so what's the problem?

Comment: i was given by my teacher the code to sort the scores in an array, but also gave us another array with the names of the players, it was already sorting the scores and she told us to make it work for the names as well, thats what i cant get to work

Comment: well, i just solved it using an array of structure. thank you all for your answers and effort to help. eventhough some of you were quite rude.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the c standart library?
Take the sort function.
Instead of having two arrays just keep one array of structs.

the sort call on cppreference.com

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort

Comment: and using that function would the names be sorted aswell?

Comment: You may sort structs instead of keeping two arrays in the same order.

Comment: ok so i'm trying to do what you said. its going like this:

This is the struct
struct scores{
    char *name;
    int score;
};

i filled the array with the names and scores already. now i'm trying to use the qsort function, i'll edit this after

Comment: qsort(/*your array of structs*/,/*number of entries * sizeof(your_struct)*/,sizeof(your_struct),strcmp());

Comment: says too few arguments to function strcmp (?)

Comment: to few  arguments are you sure? I just saw, you need a custom function as comparaisonfunction, because strcmp wants const char* and q sort gives cons void*. take this function: int cmpstr(void const *a, void const *b) { 
    char const *ca = (char const *)a;
    char const *cb = (char const *)b;

    return strcmp(ca, cb);
}

Comment: ouch my fault i should review my answer. It would have been strcmp not strcmp(), because you want to pass the function, not the return value after executing it.
But dont take strcmp directly, take cmpstr. Like this:

int cmpstr(void const *a, void const *b) { char const *ca = (char const *)a; char const *cb = (char const *)b; return strcmp(ca, cb);

//in main
qsort(/*your array of structs*/,/*number of entries * sizeof(your_struct)*/,sizeof(your_struct),cmpstr);

Comment: so it would be something like - qsort(c,4 * sizeof(c),sizeof(c),cmpstr); ?

Comment: i think so. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried it after i got the array of structure to work. it worked aswell

Answer (score 0):

This part seems curious :

```
strcpy(arr2[i], arr2[j]);
arr[j]=temp;
strcpy(arr2[i], temp2);
```

`arr2[j]` is copied to `arr2[i]`. Then `temp2` is copied to `arr2[i]`. So there is no point in coping `arr2[j]`...I guess it should be :

```
strcpy(arr2[i], arr2[j]);
arr[j]=temp;
strcpy(arr2[j], temp2);
```

I agree with @Timon : using [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) is your best option...

EDIT : Now, your issue is a question of pointer :

```
temp2=arr2[i];
strcpy(arr2[i], arr2[j]);
```

After this operation, the value of `temp2` is `arr2[j]` ! temp2 points to the content of `arr2[i]` and the content of `arr2[i]` is overwritten with `arr2[j]`. To prevent this, you will need to declare `temp2` as `char temp2[20];` and do thing like `strcpy(temp2,arr2[i]);`

Comment: yeah. i guess you're right but the issue isnt coming from that, the issue remains

Comment: i did that but right when i execute the program it stops running and tries to find a solution for the problem